# Is it correct to use Flink keyby with a large number of keys?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

If there are 10 million orders, and 200,000 or more merchants. Now I need to count the number of orders for each merchant, so I use the following method (see code). Is this correct? Because there will be a lot of keys, I don't know whether Flink will dimension each key inside, and whether it will lead to OOM?

```
orderStream.keyby(merchantId)
            
           .reduce(new ReduceFunction<Integer>() {
             @Override
              public Integer reduce(Integer value1, Integer value2)
               throws Exception {
                return value1 + value2;
            }
           });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In such a case, Flink will maintain an Integer value as managed, keyed state. So once one or more orders has been seen for each merchant, Flink's state backend will have data for each of the 200,000+ merchants.

Flink is highly scalable, so it's not a problem to have a lot of keys. `keyBy` partitions the stream so that each task manager (worker) will only handle events for a subset of the keys. (This is a sharded key/value store.) Moreover, you can choose between a heap-based state backend that keeps this state in memory, or one that uses an embedded RocksDB instance on each task manager, which keeps the state on the local disk of each task manager.

Bottom line: 200000 integers isn't very much state. Nothing to worry about, even with a single task manager.